# How to get Section without numbers in Title and TOC, but subsections with them

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, tocloft

First of all, I have been searching on the web and I have found similar cases but nothing useful for my problem, and more over, I'm pretty new in LaTeX.

## The Problem

- If I take off the numbers from `\section`, then, numbering of subsections are equal in every section (this is in the Content itself).

  ```
                                Centered Section Title
  1  Subsection
     1.1 Subsubsection
     1.2 Subsubsection
                                 Other Section Title
  1  Subsection
     1.1 Subsubsection
     1.2 Subsubsection
  ```
- It is the same in the TOC and additionally, sections are right shifted. Represented with []:

  ```
                          Index

  Introduction (manually added)......................xx
  [ ]Section Title...................................xx
  [ ]1  Subsection...................................xx
  [ ]   1.1 Subsubsection............................xx
  [ ]   1.2 Subsubsection............................xx
  [ ]Other Section Title.............................xx
  [ ]1  Subsection...................................xx
  [ ]   1.1 Subsubsection............................xx
  [ ]   1.2 Subsubsection............................xx
  Bibliography (manually added)......................xx
  ```

## What I want

- I need to get sections without numbers neither in the title nor in the TOC, but `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` must have that numeration.

  ```
                                Centered Section Title
  1.1  Subsection
     1.1.1 Subsubsection
     1.1.2 Subsubsection
                                 Other Section Title
  2.1  Subsection
     2.1.1 Subsubsection
     2.1.2 Subsubsection
  ```
- Get aligned sections in TOC.

I'm so sorry if I have miswritten something, English is not my native language

My current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=1.58in,right=0.98in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

%to do not put numbers in sections
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{\thesection}{0em}{\Large\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{}% Remove section references...
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}%... from subsections

% to fill TOC with dots
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill}%center TOC title

%to replace TOC title
\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice General}
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\paragraph{About:} Some text over here...

\section[First Things]{Capítulo 1: First Things}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Title for TOC]{Capítulo 2: Title for section}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Again for TOC]{Capítulo 3: Title for Text}

\section[Conclutions]{Conclutions}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
% Bibliography.
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Someone}
\emph{...}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found some approach to answer my own question, surely there are better than this one.

`\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{}{0em}{\Large\bfseries}` instead of
`\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{\thesection}{0em}{\Large\bfseries}` to do not write the numbers in the pages header.

and delete all `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{X}` in the document
I have deleted the first  and modified the document environment.

But I still need to **do not** write the numbers in the TOC.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to hardcode something like "Capítulo 1: First Things" in a sectional heading. The following code looks a little bulky because it does a more than you requested, but it induces a more LaTeXnish manuscript file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
  \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\secdef\@section\@ssection}
\def\@section[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \typeout{\sectionname\space\thesection.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
                    {\protect#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \fi
  \sectionmark{#1}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makesectionhead{#2}]%
  \else
    \@makesectionhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Large\bfseries \sectionname\space \thesection: #1\par\nobreak
    \fi
    \vskip 10\p@}}%
\def\@ssection#1{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makessectionhead{#1}]%
  \else
    \@makessectionhead{#1}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}%
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering\normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@}}%
\def\sectionname{Section}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice General}
  \renewcommand{\sectionname}{Sección}}% or Capítulo of course...

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\paragraph{About:} Some text over here...

\section{First Things}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Title for TOC]{Title for section}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi Ruben. The OP wants sections (starred and non-) left-aligned in the TOC.

Comment: @karlkoeller, not so sure about this because in fact the sections are somehow numbered in the running text, i.e. "Capítulo 1: First Things". I was about to add a `titletoc` solution as an addendum to my answer, in order to have a less bulky option. Now that you have written one were pretty complete here, i'd say.

Comment: @karlkoeller, ... and note that the alignment of the starred sections and the regular ones are differenetly sketched in the OP (regarding your answer). Don't knoe yet if it is important. But, it is worth a thought.

Comment: @onlycparra, does the update cover anything you need now?

Comment: Almost, because "Algo" from Section "First Things" should have number 1.1 and "Algo más" 1.1.1. "Algo" from next section should have 2.1 and "Algo más" 2.1.1... and so on Am I too confusing? :S

Comment: @onlycparra, Now it should be alright.

Comment: You are Awesome, it is perfect, I just want to know something just in a side... What should I do if I want to add Roman numbers to the Sections in the TOC (please, just comment it, because your current answer is the one I asked for)

Comment: It does not compile to me :( It says 23: Undefined control sequence. l.23 \ttl@finishall

Comment: `\ttl@finishall` is part of `titletoc` which is not in use in my solution. I suspect that it is a copy-paste-issue. Try to open a complete new `.tex` where you paste only my example and nothing else.

Comment: And for the roman page numbering in the TOC only you could use `... \pagenumbering{roman} \tableofcontents \pagenumbering{arabic} ...`

Comment: It is exactly what I did, to copy all your code and paste it in a new text file, but doesn't work :(

Comment: I did it too and it compiles. So, we have an identical input file, but a different behaviour, which is not good! Can you please send me your test file+auxiliary files via e-mail (see mny profile)?

Comment: Now, with the same steps, it works, I have not idea why, thanks, It is perfect.

Comment: Sometimes you can't explain it. Or it would just cost way too much time to find the explanation. Mainly it's good that the solution helps you now!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the package `titletoc` instead of `tocloft` to achieve what you want.

First of all, forget about redefining `\thesection`, that is remove the lines

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}% Remove section references...
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}%... from subsections
```

Then remove the stuff from `tocloft` and add these lines:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em]
              {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}
              {}
              {}
              {\mdseries\titlerule*[.75pc]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=1.58in,right=0.98in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

%to do not put numbers in sections
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{}{0em}{\Large\bfseries}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em]
              {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}
              {}
              {}
              {\mdseries\titlerule*[.75pc]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}

%to replace TOC title
\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice General}
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\paragraph{About:} Some text over here...

\section[First Things]{Capítulo 1: First Things}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Title for TOC]{Capítulo 2: Title for section}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Again for TOC]{Capítulo 3: Title for Text}

\section[Conclutions]{Conclutions}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
% Bibliography.
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Someone}
\emph{...}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

As per your comment, to have Roman numerals for sections in the TOC (although I don't approve this choice), do the following.

Declare `\thesection` as `\Roman` and `\thesubsection` as `\arabic`:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

In this case it is better to use `tocloft` instead of `titletoc`.

Add to your original settings the following lines:

```
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{3em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{5.3em}{3em}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Note that the spacing between Roman numerals and titles is deliberately large so to leave space for large numerals.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=1.58in,right=0.98in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

%to do not put numbers in sections
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering}{}{0em}{\Large\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

% to fill TOC with dots
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill}%center TOC title
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{3em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{5.3em}{3em}

%to replace TOC title
\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice General}
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\paragraph{About:} Some text over here...

\section[First Things]{Capítulo 1: First Things}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Title for TOC]{Capítulo 2: Title for section}
\subsection{Algo}
\subsubsection{Algo más}

\section[Again for TOC]{Capítulo 3: Title for Text}

\section[Conclutions]{Conclutions}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
% Bibliography.
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Someone}
\emph{...}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just one more thing.... What if I would like to add Roman numbers in front of Sections in TOC?

Comment: @onlycparra See the edit.